# ContainsKey in JSP

Tags: jsp, dictionary, struts2, jstl

I have a map `userDetailsMap<String,List<String>>` available in my jsp.
And `eligibleUser,notEligibleUser,enrolledUser` are the keys.
I can easily check for the key inside `s:iterator` tag.

Like(This code is working) :

```
<s:iterator var="userDetailsMap" value="context.userDetails">
            <s:if test="%{#userDetailsMap.key=='eligibleUser'}">
            //some code
            </s:if>
            <s:if test="%{#userDetailsMap.key=='notEligibleUser'}">
            //some code
            </s:if>
            <s:if test="%{#userDetailsMap.key=='enrolledUser'}">
            //some code
            </s:if>
</s:iterator>
```

But how I check that a particular key is present or not?
I have used :

1.

```
<s:if test="%{#userDetailsMap['eligibleUser'] == null}">
//some code
</s:if>
```

2.

```
<s:if test="%{#userDetailsMap.containsKey('eligibleUser')}">
//some code
</s:if>
```

But both of them didn't work.
Please suggest me.

Comment: Your keys are incorrect: `userDetailsMap` instead of `eligibleUser` (or another key). I don't know the syntak of OGNL, but when I see something like this, I immediately think that this `Map<String, List>` containing three keys should be replaced by a bean containing three lists.

Comment: Here we have a map rather than a key.

Comment: You're checking if `#userDetailsMap.['userDetailsMap']` is null. It makes no sense. It should be #userDetailsMap.['eligibleUser']. The map doesn't contain itself as a key.

Comment: Sorry.. Edited. Please look into this.

Comment: According to http://mycodefixes.blogspot.fr/2010/11/struts-2-creating-and-accessing-maps.html, `%{#userDetailsMap['eligibleUser'] == null}` should work. Remove the dot before the opening square bracket.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: based on your statement that your iterator works,

this is working (tested):

```
  <s:if test="context.userDetails.containsKey('eligibleUser')">
        //some code
  </s:if>
```

If your userDetail is exposed through a getter directly by the Action, then use

```
  <s:if test="userDetails.containsKey('eligibleUser')">
        //some code
  </s:if>
```

I'm assuming that UserDetails is the bean containing the authenticated user's "badge", and the three List inside the map are the Use Cases grouped by their User Role.

In this case, to print all the Use Cases based on the User Role of the authenticated user, without even knowing the keys of the roles, use:

```
    <s:iterator value="userDetailsMap">
        User Role: <s:property value="key" />
        <br/>
        <ul>
            <s:iterator value="value">
                <li>
                    Use Case: <s:property />
                </li>
            </s:iterator>               
        </ul>
    </s:iterator>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your second approach looks fine. But from the top piece of code , I would wonder are you actually wanting this?

```
 <s:if test="%{context.userDetails.containsKey('eligibleUser')}">
//some code
</s:if>
```

Please note that I have removed the `#` sign as I am not sure if you need it for a variable from the action. Correct me if I am wrong.

some ref FYI.

http://commons.apache.org/ognl/language-guide.html